# JAVA: Am not getting the number of decimal points I want

Tags: java, android

I have a code where the variable "sum" is an integer. I am trying to find the average, such that

```
int sum = 1;
float avg = 0;

//later on in the code
avg = (float)sum/37;
```

According to Android Studio debugger, the value stored in avg is 0.0, and not the desired 0.02... I want more decimal points, but my answer is getting rounded up to 1 decimal place. I tried the above code with the data type "double" and I am getting the same answer. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value using `System.out`?

Comment: My goal is to save the decimal to avg, and then compare avg >= 0. It is returning false, since it is storing avg as 0.0, and not 0.02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that operator precedence of your code resolved to:

```
avg = (float)(sum/37);
```

This means that you're still doing `int / int` math, which results in `0`, before the cast to `float`.

There are two ways to fix it:

```
avg = ((float)sum)/37; // cast sum to float before division
avg = sum/37f; // change to a float literal so sum is coerced to float for you
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
avg = sum/37f;
```

Your problem is integer/integer = integer
In your case the cast happens when the integer computation is done, which is to late.

Comment: Doing double math for a float result is overkill. Doing float math would be better.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly!